# Change JavaScript function onclick to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I am trying to get my javascript function to work in my jQuery. How it works is that you click on a text (`legend_tag`) then it gets added to the text area (`cartlist`)

```
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" id="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 1</a>
<a href="#" id="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 2</a>
<a href="#" id="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 3</a>
<a href="#" id="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 4</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    function CopyToTextarea(a){
        var text = a.textContent;
        var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
        textarea.value = textarea.value + text +'\n';
    }
</script>
```

the code above works fine:

[image: 1]

My problem is I need to translate the JavaScript function to jQuery, I tried to add:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#legend_tag").click(function CopyToTextarea(a){
        var text = a.textContent;
        var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
        textarea.value = textarea.value + text +'\n';
      });
});
```

This gives me undefined:

[image: 2]

What is my jQuery doing wrong?

tried the function outside and inside `$(document).ready`

Summary: JavaScript function to jQuery, jQuery function not working

**UPDATE:**

Tried changing `id` to `class`as pointed out, but its still undefined, same error as above:

textarea and onclick:

```
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 3</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag" onclick="CopyToTextarea(this)">item 4</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".legend_tag").click(function CopyToTextarea(a){
    var text = a.textContent;
    var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
    textarea.value = textarea.value + text +'\n';
  });
```

Comment: change `id="legend_tag"` to `class="legend_tag"` and `${"#legend_tag").click` to `${".legend_tag").click`.  `id` is unique, you can only have one of each.

Comment: I am still getting undefined after changing id to class, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#legend_tag").click(function(a) {
    var text = a.textContent;
    var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
    textarea.value = textarea.value + text + '\n';
});
```

or you can convert script completely to jQuery

```js
$(".legend_tag").on('click',function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var textarea = $('#cartlist');
        textarea.val(textarea.val() + text + '\n');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 3</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 4</a>
```

Comment: I see, this worked out well. Turns out onclick is not needed. Thanks for the clarificatoin

Answer (score 0):

As you are already binding the click event using `jQuery` there is no need to capture `onClick` event against each anchor tag. Also, within the event handler, you can capture the `event` that caused it to trigger and then reach out to the element that triggered the event using `event.target`.

```js
$(".legend_tag").click((event) => {
  var text = event.target.textContent;
  var textarea = document.getElementById('cartlist');
  textarea.value = textarea.value + text + '\n';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 3</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 4</a>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You're trying to re-use an `id`.  Each `id` must be unique.  `class` is ideal for this use case, as your anchor tags are essentially the same.
2. You're treating the argument of the event handler as if it was a DOM Element.  It's actually an Event.  You want `event.target`, or just use `this` since JQuery binds `this` to the event target.

Also, use the JQuery `.text()` to get the text value, it's generally easier than trying to use `.textContent` (because `.textContent` gets text from all descendants too, which can result in things like `undefined` showing up unexpectedly)

```js
$(function (){
    $(".legend_tag").click(function() { 
      $('#cartlist').val($('#cartlist').val() + $(this).text() +'\n')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="cartlist"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 3</a>
<a href="#" class="legend_tag">item 4</a>
```